# Capturing a X11 screenshot with ImageMagick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, x11

How can I easily take a screenshot of an X11 screen in C++ with ImageMagick++, similar to the "import" command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the source, Luke.  If you can't find it in ImageMagick++, fall back to its dependency. The code you're looking for is in ImageMagick/wand/import.c:

```
%  ImportImageCommand() reads an image from any visible window on an X server
%  and outputs it as an image file. You can capture a single window, the
%  entire screen, or any rectangular portion of the screen.  You can use the
%  display utility for redisplay, printing, editing, formatting, archiving,
%  image processing, etc. of the captured image.</dd>
```

If you don't want it to a file, you'll have to figure out what the code is doing on its own.  This appears to be the only place in the code where an actual capture of an accessible X11 display is performed, so it's your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

XGetImage on the root window?